# My Slack app redirects to the browser. How can I prevent this?

Tags: mac, macos-catalina, slack

I'm using:

- Mac OS Catalina: 10.15.5
- Slack: 4.8.0

I've previously used the Slack desktop app to work with a client and had no problems with it.

I've now set up a new instance of Slack for a new project, and upon using it I find that following the below steps I am simply redirected to the browser. Rather than the browser, how can I use the actual desktop application?

1. Open Slack application.
2. Click sign in on the application.

   - A browser tab opens.
   - You sign in using the browser.

Result:

- The usual Slack interface opens on the browser.
- The Slack application remains unchanged and:

  - You can use the sign in button once more to open up a new browser tab.

[image]

Answer (score 18):

I had found the answer on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Slack/comments/elgr21/windows_desktop_app_just_opens_my_browser/).

Open the workspace in your browser, click your name in the top left and choose "Open the Slack app" in the dropdown.

Comment: Thank you! Just to clarify, "the workspace" here means "the copy of Slack running in your browser".

Comment: This probably won't help anyone else, but I just kept signing in to Slack and on the third try a pop-up appeared asking me if I wanted to open it in the desktop application and I clicked ok and now Slack is opening there.  So maybe keep trying?

Comment: Yea, not working for me.  Signed in to slack on web because the app redirected me there. Clicking on 'Open the Slack App' opens the app with a login link that takes me back to the web.  Endless circle but never gets logged in with the App??

Comment: Thank you so much for saving me today!

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue on Mac

1. Open Slack application. Click on Sign in. It will redirect to browser
2. Complete Sign in browser (Open workspace in browser)
3. After account login in browser completes, go back to Slack application. There's option which will validate the already open account in browser and completes login in application.

Answer (score 0):

For those trying to open the Slack app in the latest version of Microsoft Edge (mine is Version `119.0.2151.72`)

When you are on your Slack browser session, try to open the app by clicking on the icon **Apps** in the top right of the browser that looks like the Microsoft logo with a broken piece and you will see a dropdown that lets you Install the App:

[image: Apps in Microsoft Edge]

Hope this helps… It took me an insane while and couldn't find the information anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

here is a workaround suggested to me by Slack support:

1. Sign in to your workspace in a web browser.
2. Once you've successfully authenticated, head to https://my.slack.com/ssb/signin_redirect/fallback
3. Click the *Copy sign-in key* button.
4. With the sign-in key still on your clipboard, open the Slack app. You should be signed into Slack automatically.

it works for Linux+KDE and will probalby work on other platforms